# How to compute the correlation coefficient between two columns from a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compute the correlation between two different columns from the same data frame. This is the code I use:

```
Correlation_unemp_demvote=np.corrcoef(New_table['unemp'],          
New_table['demVote'])

Correlation_unemp_demvote
```

The outcome as follows:

```
array([[ 1.        ,  0.34167764],
   [ 0.34167764,  1.        ]])
```

I was actually expecting to get a value between -1 and 1, as the real correlation coefficient definition explains. Could you explain to me the result I have just got? I've also seen lots of functions referred to correlations, like corr(), or correlate(). Which one should be better to be used?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`pd.Series.corr`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.corr.html) is what you want.
Do this instead

```
Correlation_unemp_demvote = New_table['unemp'].corr(New_table['demVote'])
```

---

***example***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 2), columns=list('AB'))

df.A.corr(df.B)

-0.1814956009745472
```